# Drools setting focus in decision table

Tags: drools

I'm trying to set the focus of an agenda group within an .xls spreadsheet as part of an action:

drools.setFocus("$param");

I am getting a "expression drools.setfocus is not a type" error. Doing this in a drl file is fine, but seemingly not in a decision table.

How can I get around this?

Comment: You have provided insufficient information: details about the contents of the spreadsheet cells.

Answer (score 0):

You can write an action entry:

```
[          ACTION            ]
[                            ]
[ drools.setFocus("$param"); ]
[                            ]
[         focalPoint         ]
```

Tested using 5.5.0, but there shouldn't be an issue with later versions.